# Кэширование изображений на сайте, PHP

Tags: php, изображения, кэширование

Здравствуйте. Проблема вот в чём: есть страница пользователя. При обновлении аватара или обложки, в контроллере принимается новое изображение, изменяются размеры, оно сохраняется в папку на сервере. Папка с id пользователя. Изображение перезаписывает существующее, то есть, сохраняется под этим же именем 'avatar.jpg'.
После этого принудительный редирект на страницу пользователя. Но изображение не меняется. А изменяется, лишь если нажать ctrl+F5. Как с этим бороться? Уже прописал в head такие строки:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Но ничего не изменилось. Буду рад любым советам. Если нужна ещё информация - предоставлю.

Comment: А вы не перезаписывайте, а сделайте новую ссылку на аватарку

Comment: @andreymal может хранить название аватара в БД тогда?

Comment: Так все и делают

Comment: @andreymal оу, тогда хорошо, спасибо) Но всё же интересно, почему так.

Comment: а это новые загоны хрома. У них фича какая-то новая там с усиленным кешированием

Comment: @n.osennij мда уж) Спасибо большое за ответ :)

Comment: естьвероятность, что в параллель с head отдаются абсолютно противоположные заголовки

Comment: @etki и как это проверить?

Comment: `curl -I http://my.domain.com/image.jpg`. NB: даже если там ничего нет - теги в head скорее относятся к самой странице, нежели к ресурсам на ней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При формировании ссылки на аватарку добавьте к ней метку времени, например так:

```
$avatar = '<img src="'.'URL_TO_AVATAR'.'?t='.filemtime('PATH_TO_FILE_OF_AVATAR')).'" alt="">';
```

тогда при перезаписи файла время возвращаемое функцией [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php) будет меняться, что изменит ссылку на аватарку.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Visman, a `filemtime` не "тяжелая"? Будет ли оптимальней по скорости хранить таймштамп в базе?

Comment: Не тяжёлая она. Тормозов на форумах использующий такой метод не замечено.

Comment: @br3t, хотя средствами apache/nginx было бы лучше отдавать нужные заголовки, думаю.

Comment: @Visman на самом деле способ со временем мощнее. Главное преимущество - можно настроить ресурсы (заголовками) на "вечное" кеширование, радикально снизив тем самым число запросов к серверу без перекладывания на пользователя таких действий как очистка кеша.