# http кэшированя изображений

Tags: php, apache, http

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как кэшировать картинки.
Допустим есть изображение example.com/img/img1.jpg, в заголовках у него допустим

```
Date:Thu, 18 May 2017 06:15:34 GMT
ETag:"7dab5-54f91340112ce"
Last-Modified:Mon, 15 May 2017 14:52:24 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

Я изменяю картинку и, я так понимаю, нужно изменить заголовок Last-Modified на уровне Apache.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Есть такой метод https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640200/186083 если вы php используете.

Comment: @Visman да, сейчас как раз так и работает через get параметр. Но задача стоит сделать правильно, то есть через заголовки