# Как отключить кеширование файлов Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с одной проблемой. Есть сайт на Wordpress. На сайте администратор через ftp заменяет pdf файлы. В итоге новые файлы можно увидеть только, если сбросить кеш через ctrl+f5. Иногда приходится кеш браузера очищать. Плагины для кеширования не стоят. Есть только wp-security, но его отключения ситуацию не меняет

Comment: Так проблема кеширования на сервере или в браузере?

Comment: Получается, что в браузере. Раз очистка кеша в браузере помогает

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640200/221753 , там про картинки, но со стилями тоже можно

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Проблема в pdf файлах

Comment: "новые файлы можно увидеть " - увидеть где? У вас какой-то вэб-интерфейс для просмотра ftp-папок?

Comment: Через filezilla загружается обновленный файл. А через браузер виден старый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кэширование не в WordPress, а на сервере. Браузер читает заголовки, которые ему отдаёт apache или nginx. Там стоит время кэширования. Браузер запоминает это время для каждого файла и при следующем обновлении страницы вообще не обращается к серверу за этим файлом, а вытаскивает его из локального кэша.

Ctrl+F5 даёт сигнал браузеру - забудь про локальный кэш, грузи всё с сервера снова. Он и грузит.

Так, если сильно упрощённо, происходит взаимодействие клиента (браузера) и сервера. WordPress ни при чём.

Что делать с файлами? Обычно к файлам добавляют номера версий после ?. Вы можете видеть, как это делает WP, например: `style.css?ver=4.8`.

**UPDATE**

В связи с тем, что вопрос уточнён. Вы можете добавить такой код в .htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|pdf)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а что значит Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"?

Comment: Это значит, что мы говорим - файл устарел еще в 1984 году (это самая ранняя дата, которую можно указать)

Comment: @KAGGDesign Pragmа не нужно и даже [вредно](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85/#post-244839). А вообще лучше генерировать ссылки на эти файлы с параметром, зависим от даты.файла (аналогично версии ВП).

Comment: @SeVlad Прочитал внимательно, спасибо за инфу. Но одного не могу понять. Ну, отменили pragma в WP 4.6 за ненадобностью (устарела). А вред-то в чем?

Comment: @KAGGDesign одно из вредных проявлений - как раз тема того топика: не возможно отредактировать или даже написать новый пост (ну и не только пост же). И это нередкая ситуация и везде, где встречалось именно из-за Pragma. А отменили не ВП, В ВП лишь убрали поддержку того, чего не должно быть на серверах. Отменили в http-протоколе.